# How to compare two jbyte Arrays in Android NDK

Tags: android, arrays, android-ndk, java-native-interface, byte

I am new to NDK and learning.

I managed to call the native method from java code but don't know how can I compare two `jbyte` arrays

here is what I have:

```
 jbyte bytes1[] = {48, -126, 1,4};
 jbyte bytes2[] = {48, -126, 1,4};

 jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, bytes1);
 jmethodID   mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "equals", "([B)Z");
 jboolean isEqual = (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env, bytes1, mid, bytes2);
```

I know above code is wrong but is there a correct way of comparing the byte arrays

Comment: Since they are byte arrays, are you sure you need the functionality of the equals method? You could write own custom code for it, comparing them byte by byte, in a loop. *jbyte* resolves to byte, so it will be working.

Comment: Correction to previous comment: *jbyte* resolves to *signed char* in Android.

Comment: @ThomasCalc in Java a byte is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.

Comment: Do you want to compare them in your C++ code or in your Java code? The answer is different for each one.

Comment: @auselen: we are talking about C++ code based on the OP's post. In Android, in the native headers, jbyte is defined as a signed char (and this exactly corresponds to what you said: 8-bit signed integer). I merely pointed out that the OP can use custom code (instead of invoking *Equals*) for his/her goal. This is basically what the accepted answer contains, too.

Comment: @ThomasCalc "signed char" is not an exactly defined type. that was my point. (it is also C we are talking about, but shouldn't matter for C++ as well). however jbyte is an "8-bit signed two's complement integer".

Comment: @auselen: directly from Android source code (jni.h): **typedef int8_t jbyte;**. Further resolving *int8_t* (still from official Android source): **typedef signed char int8_t;**. So "exactly defined" depends on what you mean. If it wasn't well-defined -- in fact, *formal* -- it couldn't occur in a programming language and in the official Android source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use memcmp if you need to compare two jbyte arrays.

```
#include <string.h>
int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

In your example,

```
jboolean isEqual = (memcmp(bytes1, bytes2, 4) == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for hardcoded values. Do you know how can I compare `jbyteArray` with some harcoded value(`jbyte []`) in c. where `jbyteArray` is passed from java code to native code.

Comment: Thanks again. I converted `jbyteArray` to `jbyte[]` using `GetByteArrayRegion(env, src, 0, 10, dest)`